# Possibility of having ThirdPersonController in Unity not user-controlled?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using unity and I am creating a simple game where the user controls the movement of a RollerBall around some obstacles while trying to collect coins. What I am trying to do is have enemies spawn around the platform that chase the RollerBall, but I am trying to use the ThirdPersonController as the enemies that pop up. I just want to know if it is possible to have the ThirdPersonController that Unity provides not user-controlled or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You don't need any input to move with the controller. Just get a move direction, and apply it with the Move function. Something similar to this:

```
characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();    
moveDirection = new Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f);
characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
```